# Detecting console.log() calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, tdd, error-logging

I'm trying to write a test case for a debugging method that writes messages to the JavaScript console using `console.log()`. The test has to check that the message has been successfully written to the console. I'm using jQuery.

Is there a way to attach a hook to `console.log()` or otherwise check that a message has been written to the console, or any other suggestions on how to write the test case?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`console.log` doesn't keep a record of messages that are logged, or emit any events that you could listen for. It's not possible for your tests to directly verify its output from JavaScript. Instead, your test code will need to replace `console.log` with a **mock** implementation that does keep track of log messages for later verification.

Mocking is a common feature supported by most JavaScript test frameworks. For example, [the Jest test framework provides a `jest.spyOn` function](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname) which replaces a given method with a mock implementation that records the arguments for each call [in a `.mock` property](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-property) before passing them on to the original implementation. After each test you may want to call [`jest.clearAllMocks()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestclearallmocks) to reset the recorded argument lists for the next test, or use [the equivalent `clearMocks: true` config option](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#clearmocks-boolean).

```
function saySomething() {
  console.log("Hello World");
}
```

```
jest.spyOn(console, 'log');

test("saySomething says hello", () => {
  expect(console.log.mock.calls.length).toBe(0);
  saySomething();
  expect(console.log.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
  expect(console.log.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe("Hello World");
});

afterEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});
```

If you're not using a test framework (you probably should), you can create a simple mock yourself.

```
function saySomething() {
  console.log("Hello World");
}
```

```
function testSomething() {
  // Replace console.log with stub implementation.
  const originalLog = console.log;
  const calls = [];
  console.log = (...args) => {
    calls.push(args);
    originalLog(...args);
  };

  try {
    console.assert(calls.length == 0);
    saySomething();
    console.assert(calls.length == 1);
    console.assert(calls[0][0] == "Hello World");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } finally {
    // Restore original implementation after testing.
    console.log = originalLog;
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. So simple but it wouldn't have occurred to me.

Comment: This doesn't handle when you give multiple arguments to `console.log`, it throws away all but the first.

Comment: @nh2 True enough! Fixed.

Answer (score 10):

So not bad solutions, but if you're looking for a high powered logger try Paul Irish's [log()](http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/)

If that's too high powered, you can get by with something like this.

```
var console = window.console,
    _log = console ? console.log : function(){};

_log.history = [];

console.log = function( ){
  _log.history.push.apply( _log.history, arguments );
  _log.apply( console, arguments );
}
```

Usage

```
console.log('I','have','an','important','message');
//Use native one instead
_log.call( console, _log.history );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BeXdM/

Comment: How can I check if something exists in the log then ?

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Jasmine, it's dead simple:

```
it('is my test', function () {
    spyOn(console, 'log');
    // do your stuff that should log something
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('something');
});
```

Head to [Jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html) for more info.

Comment: Or, if using Jest (which is essentially built onto, or off of, Jasmine), just replace the `spyOn...` line with `console.log = jest.fn();`.

Answer (score 7):

Just attach your own function to console.log. 
On your page, after everything loads,

Before starting tests -

```
var originalLog = console.log;
console.log = function(msg){
  alert('my .log hook received message - '+msg); 
  //add your logic here
}
```

After running tests, if necessary  -

```
console.log = originalLog
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way out is to use the NPM package [`std-mocks`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/std-mocks).

From their documentation:

```js
var stdMocks = require('std-mocks');
 
stdMocks.use();
process.stdout.write('ok');
console.log('log test\n');
stdMocks.restore();
 
var output = stdMocks.flush();
console.log(output.stdout); // ['ok', 'log test\n']
```

**Note**: make sure you `stdMocks.restore()` before your assertions so your test runner is still able to log information about failed assertions.