# How to test React PropTypes through Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, reactjs-testutils, react-proptypes

I'm writing Jest tests for my React code and hoping to make use of/test the PropType checks. I am quite new to the Javascript universe. I'm using npm to install `react-0.11.2` and have a simple:

```
var React = require('react/addons');
```

In my tests. My test looks quite similar to the jest/react tutorial example with code like:

```js
var eventCell = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
  <EventCell
    slot={slot}
    weekId={weekId}
    day={day}
    eventTypes={eventTypes}
    />
);

var time = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(eventCell, 'time');
expect(time.getDOMNode().textContent).toEqual('19:00 ');
```

However it seems that the PropType checks in the `EventCell` component aren't being triggered. I understand that the checks are only run in Development mode but then I also thought that getting `react` through npm gave you the development version. The checks trigger in my browser when I build the component with watchify.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `PropType` you are using? I test mine by spying on `console.warn`.

Comment: For EventCell, I'm using number.isRequired and object.isRequired. I've not looked at it for a long time and I'm not sure how to go about using console.warn. Is the console available in node.js which is running the jest test?

Comment: Yes, it should available.

Comment: Does running your tests with `NODE_ENV=development` solve the problem?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The underlying problem is [How to test `console.log`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246884/detecting-console-log-calls)

The short answer is that you should replace the `console.{method}` for the duration of the test. The common approach is to use [spies](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.0.0/spies/). In this particular case, you might want to use [stubs](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.0.0/stubs/) to prevent the output.

Here is an example implementation using [Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) (Sinon.js provides standalone spies, stubs and mocks):

```js
import {
    expect
} from 'chai';
import DateName from './../../src/app/components/DateName';
import createComponent from './create-component';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('DateName', () => {
    it('throws an error if date input does not represent 12:00:00 AM UTC', () => {
        let stub;

        stub = sinon.stub(console, 'error');

        createComponent(DateName, {date: 1470009600000});

        expect(stub.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
        expect(stub.calledWithExactly('Warning: Failed propType: Date unix timestamp must represent 00:00:00 (HH:mm:ss) time.')).to.equal(true);

        console.error.restore();
    });
});
```

In this example `DataName` component will throw an error when initialised with a timestamp value that does not represent a precise date (12:00:00 AM).

I am stubbing the `console.error` method (This is what Facebook `warning` module is using internally to generate the error). I ensure that the stub has been called once and with exactly one parameter representing the error.

Comment: I think this answer should be marked as the accepted answer.It's a much cleaner solution and provides a test to the exact behaviour the browser would have.

Comment: Is there any reason `sinon` is being used here? (I've used `jasmine` and  `spyOn` doesn't seem to be rest between specs). Am wondering perhaps certain test frameworks (`sinon`?) do this better.

Comment: @AdamT I assume because the example uses Chai as an assertion library, which isn't as fully-featured as Jasmine. I don't believe there is a significant difference between Sinon and Jasmine.

Comment: If the expectation fails, how does the console get restored?  Seems like the stub should in a beforeEach and the restore in an afterEach.

Comment: See [this other SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41916993/5218951) for a discussion of some inherent limitations to using a spy/mock of `console.error` for testing `propTypes`.

Comment: This solution is not suitable for tests, for the reasons linked to by @AndrewWillems. I just published a package that provides an alternative checkPropTypes function that is suitable for use in tests: https://github.com/ratehub/check-prop-types

Comment: This doesnt work for me -  Expected: true Received: false. Assume the stub is never called

Answer (score 14):

**Intro**

The answer by @Gajus definitely helped me (so, **thanks Gajus**). However, I thought I would provide an answer that:

- Uses a more **up-to-date React** (v15.4.1)
- Uses **Jest** (which comes with React)
- Allows testing **multiple prop values** for a single prop
- Is **more generic**

**Summary**

Like the approach suggested here by Gajus and elsewhere by others, the basic approach I'm suggesting is also to **determine whether or not `console.error` is used by React in response to an unacceptable test prop value**. Specifically, this approach involves doing the following for each test prop value:

- **mocking and clearing `console.error`** (to ensure prior calls to `console.error` aren't interfering),
- **creating the component using the test prop value** under consideration, and
- **confirming whether or not `console.error` was fired** as expected.

**The `testPropTypes` Function**

The following code can be placed either within the test or as a separate imported/required module/file:

```
const testPropTypes = (component, propName, arraysOfTestValues, otherProps) => {
    console.error = jest.fn();
    const _test = (testValues, expectError) => {
        for (let propValue of testValues) {
            console.error.mockClear();
            React.createElement(component, {...otherProps, [propName]: propValue});
            expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expectError ? 1 : 0);
        }
    };
    _test(arraysOfTestValues[0], false);
    _test(arraysOfTestValues[1], true);
};
```

**Calling the Function**

Any test examining `propTypes` can **call `testPropTypes`** using three or four **parameters**:

- `component`, the React **component** that is modified by the prop;
- `propName`, the string **name of the prop** under test;
- `arraysOfTestValues`, an array of arrays of **all the desired test values** of the prop to be tested:

  - the first sub-array contains all **acceptable** test prop values, while
  - the second sub-array contains all **unacceptable** test prop values; and
- optionally, `otherProps`, an object containing **prop name/value pairs for any other required props** of this component.

  The `otherProps` object is needed to ensure React doesn't make irrelevant calls to `console.error` because other required props are inadvertently missing. Simply include a single acceptable value for any required props, e.g. `{requiredPropName1: anyAcceptableValue, requiredPropName2: anyAcceptableValue}`.

**Function Logic**

The function does the following:

- It **sets up a mock of `console.error`** which is what React uses to report props of incorrect type.
- For **each sub-array** of test prop values provided it **loops through each test prop value** in each sub-array to test for prop type:

  - The first of the two sub-arrays should be a list of **acceptable test prop values**.
  - The second should be of **unacceptable test prop values**.
- Within the loop for each individual test prop value, **the `console.error` mock is first cleared** so that any error messages detected can be assumed to have come from this test.
- An instance of the **component is then created using the test prop value** as well as any other necessary required props not currently being tested.
- Finally, a check is made to **see whether a warning has been triggered**, which should happen if your test tried to create a component using an inappropriate or missing prop.

**Testing for Optional versus Required Props**

Note that assigning `null` (or `undefined`) to a prop value is, from React's perspective, essentially the same thing as not providing any value for that prop. By definition this is acceptable for an optional prop but unacceptable for a required one. Thus, **by placing `null` in either the array of acceptable or unacceptable values you test whether that prop is optional or required respectively**.

**Example Code**

*MyComponent.js (just the `propTypes`):*

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
    myProp1: React.PropTypes.number,      // optional number
    myProp2: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([  // required number or array of numbers
        React.PropTypes.number,
        React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.number)
    ]).isRequired
```

*MyComponent.test.js:*

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {

    it('should accept an optional number for myProp1', () => {
        const testValues = [
            [0, null],   // acceptable values; note: null is acceptable
            ['', []] // unacceptable values
        ];
        testPropTypes(MyComponent, 'myProp1', testValues, {myProp2: 123});
    });

    it('should require a number or an array of numbers for myProp2', () => {
        const testValues = [
            [0, [0]], // acceptable values
            ['', null] // unacceptable values; note: null is unacceptable
        ];
        testPropTypes(MyComponent, 'myProp2', testValues);
    });
});
```

**Limitation of This Approach (IMPORTANT)**

There are currently some significant limitations on how you can use this approach which, if over-stepped, could be the source of some hard-to-trace testing bugs. The reasons for, and implications of, these limitations are explained in [this other SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41916993/5218951). In summary, for simple prop types, like for `myProp1`, you can test as many unacceptable non-`null` test prop values as you want *as long as they are all of different data types*. For some complex prop types, like for `myProp2`, you can only test a *single* unacceptable non-`null` prop value *of any type*. See that other question/answer for a more in-depth discussion.

Comment: i think you made a typo on the testPropTypes function, should it be: React.createElement(component, {...otherProps, [propName]: propValue});  ?? (notice component instead of Toolbar)

Comment: You're right. It's fixed now. As you may have guessed, the typo was a left-over from converting my own specific code into something generic that was more appropriate for StackOverflow. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how many people do this, but I have a custom validator function which, internally, is calling `PropTypes.checkPropTypes(...)`. Using `console.error = jest.fn()`, as explained here, was the solution to testing the validator function that worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Mocking `console.error` is not suitable for use in unit tests! @AndrewWillems linked to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916992/why-does-my-jest-test-of-react-proptypes-break-when-using-multiple-unacceptable/41916993#41916993) in a comment above that describes the problems with this approach.

Check out [this issue on facebook/prop-types](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/issues/28) for discussion about the ability for that library to throw instead of logging propType errors (at the time of writing, it's not supported).

I have published a helper library to provide that behaviour in the mean time, [check-prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/check-prop-types). You can use it like this:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import checkPropTypes from 'check-prop-types';

const HelloComponent = ({ name }) => (
  <h1>Hi, {name}</h1>
);

HelloComponent.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

let result = checkPropTypes(HelloComponent.propTypes, { name: 'Julia' }, 'prop', HelloComponent.name);
assert(`result` === null);

result = checkPropTypes(HelloComponent.propTypes, { name: 123 }, 'prop', HelloComponent.name);
assert(`result` === 'Failed prop type: Invalid prop `name` of type `number` supplied to `HelloComponent`, expected `string`.');
```

Answer (score 5):

A new package [jest-prop-type-error](https://github.com/esphen/jest-prop-type-error) is simple to add and fails on `PropType` errors:

Install via:

```
yarn add -D jest-prop-type-error
```

Then add the following to your `package.json`'s `setupFiles` in the `jest` section:

```
"setupFiles": [
  "jest-prop-type-error"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since ReactJS will only send warnings to the console but will not actually throw an error, I test prop values in this way:

```
var myTestElement = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
<MyTestElement height={100} /> );

it("check MyTestElement props", function() {

   expect( typeof myTestElement.props.height ).toEqual ( 'number' );

});
```

Comment: This way you're reimplementing the proptypes in the test.

Comment: How do you test shape then? See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736470/how-to-test-a-react-component-proptypes-validation

Answer (score 1):

For unit tests based on Jest, using this on your `setup.js` will fail any test where `console.error` (prop-type errors) or `console.warn` (React compat issues, like still using `componentWillUpdate`) ends up being called:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.spyOn(console, 'error')
  jest.spyOn(console, 'warn')
})

afterEach(() => {
  /* eslint-disable no-console,jest/no-standalone-expect */
  expect(console.error).not.toBeCalled()
  expect(console.warn).not.toBeCalled()
})
```

This breaks when any test calls `jest.restoreAllMocks()` - for us, calling 
jest.clearAllMocks()` instead helped.

It also requires your app to not call `console.error` or `console.warn` for "error handling" (scare quotes, since that's usually not a good idea).

Comment: Can you clarify on why there's the  eslint-disable comment?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I tested PropType Errors in React using `Sinon`. Also, to check the error for each missing prototype try `console.log(sinon.assert.notCalled(console.error))`.

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import DateName from './../../src/app/components/DateName';
import sinon from 'sinon';
    
describe('DateName', () => {

  function renderComponent(date) {
    return render(
        <DateName date={date} />
    );
  }

  it('throws an error if date input does not represent 12:00:00 AM UTC', () => {
          let stub;
          stub = sinon.stub(console, 'error');
          renderComponent(undefined);
          expect(stub.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
          sinon.assert.calledWithMatch(console.error,'Warning: Failed %s type: %s%s', 'prop', 'The prop `date` is marked as required in `DateName`, but its value is `undefined`.');
          console.error.restore();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the React Testing Lib
https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html

Dog.js

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Dog {
    constructor(breed, dob, weight) {
        this.breed = breed;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}

Dog.propTypes = {
    breed: PropTypes.string,
    dob: PropTypes.instanceOf(Date),
    weight: PropTypes.number,
};
```

Dog.spec.js

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Dog from './Dog';

describe('Dog.js tests', () => {
    const mockData = {
        breed: 'Shiba Inu',
        dob: new Date('March 14, 2017 08:30:00'),
        weight: 21,
    }

    const instance = {
        name: 'MockDogComponent',
        model: new Dog(mockData),
    };

    beforeEach(() => {
        const { breed, dob, weight } = mockData;
        instance.model = new Dog(breed, dob, weight);
    });

    it('should have valid propTypes', () => {        
        Object.keys(instance.model).forEach((prop) => 
            expect(PropTypes
                .checkPropTypes(Dog.propTypes, instance.model, prop, instance.name))
                .toBeUndefined()
            );
    });
```