# Why does my Jest test of React propTypes break when using multiple unacceptable prop values?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

In [an answer to a different SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41885867/5218951) about how to test `propTypes` in React using Jest, I proposed a solution that mocks `console.error`, something others have done before but which I thought could be improved. My solution, a function, is below. The example code below contains some arbitrary `propTypes` that are then tested. For each test, I expected the first sub-array of "acceptable values" to not cause the mock of `console.error` to have been called by React, but I expected each test prop value in the second sub-array of "unacceptable values" to cause the mock to have been called.

**The `testPropTypes` Function**

```
const testPropTypes = (component, propName, arraysOfTestValues, otherProps) => {
    console.error = jest.fn();
    const _test = (testValues, expectError) => {
        for (let propValue of testValues) {
            console.error.mockClear();
            React.createElement(component, {...otherProps, [propName]: propValue});
            expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expectError ? 1 : 0);
        }
    };
    _test(arraysOfTestValues[0], false);
    _test(arraysOfTestValues[1], true);
};
```

**Example Code**

*MyComponent.js (just the `propTypes`):*

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
    myProp1: React.PropTypes.number,      // optional number
    myProp2: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([  // required number or array of numbers
        React.PropTypes.number,
        React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.number)
    ]).isRequired
```

*MyComponent.test.js:*

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {

    it('should accept an optional number for myProp1', () => {
        const testValues = [
            [0, null],                   // acceptable values
            ['', {}, [], Symbol(), true] // unacceptable values
        ];
        testPropTypes(MyComponent, 'myProp1', testValues, {myProp2: 123});
    });

    it('should require a number or an array of numbers for myProp2', () => {
        const testValues = [
            [0, [0]],                          // acceptable values
            ['', {}, [], Symbol(), true, null] // unacceptable values
        ];
        testPropTypes(MyComponent, 'myProp2', testValues);
    });
});
```

The code seems to work fine in simple circumstances. However, the sub-array of unacceptable test prop values for the more complex `propType`, i.e. for `myProp2`, produces some funny results. The presence or absence of `null` (which tests for whether the prop is optional or required) makes no difference, i.e. it behaves properly all the time. However, the other test prop type values seem to interact with each other in some mysterious way. If a single non-`null` unacceptable test prop value is used, the test performs as expected. However, if more than one such non-`null` unacceptable test prop value is used, the test breaks, responding as if the second, third, etc. unacceptable types (again, other than `null`) are actually acceptable.

What's going on and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short Answer**

The short answer is that, for at least some complex `propTypes` like for `myProp2`, you can only include a single non-`null` test prop type of any type. This is an inherent limitation to this approach, and comes from a built-in characteristic of React/Jest that causes multiple error conditions that might otherwise have produced identical error messages to be reported only once. In fact, even for simple `propTypes` like for `myProp1`, a related but slightly more hidden limitation also exists: you can include any number of different unacceptable non-`null` test prop values, but never more than one *of the same type*. e.g. `['', {}, []]` will work but `['', 'x', {}, []]` will not (note that there are two strings).

This limitation is important as there doesn't currently seem to be a better way of testing `propTypes` in React. However, the constraints this places on this approach seem manageable, allowing `propTypes` to still be reasonably tested.

**Details**

There are currently some significant limitations on how you can use this approach (i.e. mocking `console.error`) which, if over-stepped, could be the source of some hard-to-trace testing bugs.

The source of these limitations is a behaviour of React (or perhaps Jest in response to React?) that is built-in to its error reporting mechanism. It currently only seems to produce multiple `console.error` messages, at least for `propTypes` issues, when those messages are distinct from each other. Presumably the rationale behind this is that repeated identical messages provide no new information and so such a message should only be shown the first time, which seems reasonable. The implication of this, though, is that two distinct error conditions which, when they occur separately, produce identical error messages only result in a single error message when they occur within the same test run. All subsequent identical messages are suppressed. This has several further implications for strategies such as this one that necessarily expect the output from `console.error` to exactly correlate with test-failing conditions, as follows.

Currently, for simple `propTypes` (like that for `myProp1` in the example code), distinct error messages seem to appear for all unacceptable prop values of different data types, e.g.

```
"Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'myProp1' of type 'string'
supplied to 'MyComponent', expected 'number'."
```

However, the error message for a second test prop value *of the same type* seems to have its expected error message suppressed. Thus an array of unacceptable values all of different data types, such as `[123, [123], '123']`, will cause each to produce an error message as expected, allowing the test to work. However, an array of unacceptable values in which some have the identical data types, such as `[123, 456, [123], '123']`, will *not* work, as only the first value of any particular data type will produce the expected error message, and so the presumed error messages for any subsequent similarly-typed values will be suppressed, breaking the test. Thus, for simple `propTypes`, you can use as many unacceptable test prop values as you want *as long as they are all of different data types*. This doesn't seem like a big problem, as you shouldn't need to test more than one value of a particular data type anyway, but you need to be aware of this caveat.

Perhaps even more importantly, however, some complex `propTypes` (like that for `myProp2`) paradoxically (though perhaps reasonably) result in even more simplified error messages, e.g.

```
"Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'myProp2' supplied to 'MyComponent'."
```

This means, though, that only the first non-`null` unacceptable test prop value *of any data type* produces an error message, with *all* subsequent tests using other unacceptable values having their error messages suppressed. Thus, with such complex `propTypes`, unfortunately you can include *only a single* unacceptable prop value for a particular prop for a particular component in your test suite. This does not include a `null` or `undefined` value for a required complex `propType`, as these values produce a distinct error message which is thus not suppressed. Note, however, that you still *can* test as many *acceptable* values as you want, e.g. allowing you to test multiple possible acceptable prop values for `myProp2` in the example code. Even more confusingly, this limitation holds not just within a test *but between tests*. Thus, any test suite can only contain a single unacceptable prop type test for a particular prop for a particular component. This does seem like a significant limitation, and it is absolutely necessary to keep it in mind. However, it actually might not be that limiting as it initially might sound, as one wouldn't typically expect to test unacceptable values for a particular prop for a particular component multiple times anyway. Thus this approach, i.e. mocking `console.error`, still seems reasonable, and still seems the only real way of testing `propTypes` anyway.

Note that this limitation could change in the future, any time that React and/or Jest changes how it uses `console.error` in response to inappropriate prop values.

Note also that I haven't investigated exactly how React/Jest perform error reporting for other complex `propTypes`, e.g. `React.PropTypes.arrayOf`, `... .objectOf`, `... .shape`, etc. Presumably, to test these robustly you would first need to investigate what kind of error messages are produced for inappropriate values as well as which if any such messages are suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of detail on the *why*, to expand on Andrew Willems' detailed description of the conditions causing the problem.

Note that my explanation here applies to the `prop-types` library that Facebook extracted from React recently, specifically when checking props with the `checkPropTypes` function it exports.

The [`checkPropTypes.js`](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/be165febc8133dfbe2c45133db6d25664dd68ad8/checkPropTypes.js) module keeps mutable state in the form of an object called `loggedTypeFailures` on [line 16](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/be165febc8133dfbe2c45133db6d25664dd68ad8/checkPropTypes.js#L16):

```
 var loggedTypeFailures = {};
```

[Lines 47-50](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/be165febc8133dfbe2c45133db6d25664dd68ad8/checkPropTypes.js#L47-L50) show how it is used and explain the thinking:

```
      if (error instanceof Error && !(error.message in loggedTypeFailures)) {
        // Only monitor this failure once because there tends to be a lot of the
        // same error.
        loggedTypeFailures[error.message] = true;
```

When a propType check fails, the message is set as a key on `loggedTypeFailures` before logging the error, to track that it has already been logged. The next time a propType fails with the same message, the `error.message in loggedTypeFailures` check succeeds and logging is skipped.

Since `loggedTypeFailures` is private to the module, there is no way to access or reset it.

---

If you need to detect propType failures in a more robust way (eg., for unit tests), I published a tiny library that helps: [check-prop-types](https://github.com/ratehub/check-prop-types). It checks props the same way as `checkPropTypes.js`, but returns the error instead of logging it.