# Access captured stderr output in Jest

Tags: jestjs

Jest captures the stdout and stderr output. Is it possible to access this captured information in a test?

Regards, nidkil

Comment: what do you mean? are you talking about `console.log`/`console.error` output initiated by JS code or exception/syntax error/build error messages?

Comment: I was using the wrong approach. See the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going about this in the wrong way. Instead of using spy/mock I was trying to intercept stdout/stderr directly. I solved it using the following function.

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
export function spyConsole() {
  let spy = {}

  beforeEach(() => {
    spy.console = jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation(() => {})
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    spy.console.mockClear()
  })

  afterAll(() => {
    spy.console.mockRestore()
  })

  return spy
}
```

Which is used in the following way:

```
import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { spyConsole } from '@tst/helpers/test-utils'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import VBtnPlus from '@/components/common/VBtnPlus.vue'

describe('VStatsCard.vue', () => {
  let localVue = null

  beforeEach(() => {
    localVue = createLocalVue()
    localVue.use(Vuetify)
  })

  describe('test prop warnings', () => {
    let spy = spyConsole()

    it('displays warning messages when both label and icon are not specified', () => {
      mount(VBtnPlus, {
        localVue: localVue
      })
      expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
      expect(spy.console.mock.calls[0][0]).toContain(
        '[Vue warn]: Missing required prop, specify at least one of the following: "label" or "icon"'
      )
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: so you actually need to test props validation in VueJs. besides mocking `console.error` obviously works for you(but I'd not rely on that much - say in similar scenario React has performance-related optimization so there [are limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916992/why-does-my-jest-test-of-react-proptypes-break-when-using-multiple-unacceptable/41916993#41916993) - who knows if VueJS has something similar). Second thing is you need to hard-code error message in the test. And that may change in future. Finally it's quite hard to read.

Comment: what to do? just test `cm.$vm.options.<prop name>.required` or `cm.$vm.options.<prop name>.validator()` to work properly as suggested at https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/34 I believe tests would be more readable and more stable in time

Answer (score 0):

If you came across this post trying to test pino logging, I was able to test my pino configuration with jest by doing the following (credit to [How to use Jest to test that pino debug log is written to stdout when load a module in a test?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62678492/))

```js
import { streamSym } from 'pino/lib/symbols'
import logger from './logger' // where my pino config is

describe('Logger default configuration', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks()
    jest.restoreAllMocks()
  })
  it('Logs an error', () => {
    const spyOnLoggerError = jest.spyOn(logger, 'error')
    const spyOnLoggerStreamWrite = jest.spyOn(logger[streamSym], 'write')
    const myTestError = new Error('My test error')
    logger.error(myTestError)
    expect(spyOnLoggerError).toBeCalledWith(myTestError) // verify logger.error called
    expect(spyOnLoggerStreamWrite).toBeCalledTimes(1) // verify that logger.error was only called once
    expect(spyOnLoggerStreamWrite).toBeCalledWith(expect.stringContaining('"level":50')) // validate log level of message
    expect(spyOnLoggerStreamWrite).toBeCalledWith(expect.stringContaining('"message":"My test error"')) // validate that message contains error message
  })
})
```

Make sure when testing that the log `level` in the pino config is set to a value that will actually log the result.  For instance, my default `level` is set to 'error' which is why the test passes.  However, I would need to mock my environment variable that sets the `level` if I needed to test `logger.trace(new Error('Some trace error'))`.

UPDATE:
Note that I previously tried to use `jest.spyOn((global.console as any)._stdout, 'write')`, but this proved to be unreliable and failed when I ran all of the tests.

For reference, here is my pino config (`./logger.ts`):

```js
// logger.ts
import { isPlainObject } from 'lodash'
import pino, { Logger } from 'pino'
import pinoCaller from 'pino-caller'
import pinoStdSerializers from 'pino-std-serializers'

const normalSerializer = (value): string => {
  if (typeof value === 'object') return JSON.stringify(value)
  if (typeof value === 'undefined') return 'undefined'
  return value
}

const isError = (value): boolean => value instanceof Error

const appName = 'myAppName'
const logLevel = process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'error'

const pinoLogger = pino({
  name: `${appName}`,
  level: logLevel,
  hooks: {
    logMethod(args, method): void {
      const arrayArgs = Array.from(args)
      arrayArgs.forEach(arg => {
        const isArgError = isError(arg)
        const doesArgContainErrorValue = isPlainObject(arg) && Object.values(arg).some(val => isError(val))
        const isErrorFoundInArg = isArgError || doesArgContainErrorValue // use the error serializer if the argument is an instance of error or prop value is instance of error
        const serializer = isErrorFoundInArg ? pinoStdSerializers.err : normalSerializer
        method.apply(this, [serializer(arg)])
      })
    },
  },
  prettyPrint: process.env.ENABLE_PRETTY_LOG === 'true',
})

/**
 * Accepted logger arguments are as follows:
 * logger.trace(err) // where the argument err is an instance of Error
 * logger.info({ err, myCtx: {prop1: 'some value'} }) // where the argument is an object with err being an instanceof Error and myCtx being some arbitrary context object
 * logger.warn({prop1: 1, prop2: 2}) // where the argument is an arbitrary object
 * logger.error('My String')
 */
const logger = process.env.ENABLE_LOG_CALL_DETAILS === 'true' ? pinoCaller(pinoLogger) : pinoLogger

export default logger
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just came across the same problem / questions and ending using [std-mocks](https://github.com/gregberge/std-mocks) while testing my logger ([Logger.test.js#L29](https://github.com/nolddor/steam-badges-db/blob/main/lib/__tests__/Logger.test.js#L29))

*See an example:*

```
const stdMocks = require("std-mocks");

stdMocks.use();
process.stdout.write("ok");
console.log("log test\n");
stdMocks.restore();

var output = stdMocks.flush();
console.log(output.stdout); // ['ok', 'log test\n']
```