# How to test a React component propTypes validation

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-proptypes

How can I unit test the propTypes validation of a React component for `PropTypes.shape`?

My component propTypes validation:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  propA: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  propB: PropTypes.shape({
    inner1: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    inner2: PropTypes.func,
  }).isRequired,
}
```

My unit test:

```
describe('MyComponent propTypes validation', () => {
  it('validates propA', () => {
    expect(MyComponent.propTypes.propA).toBe(PropTypes.string.isRequired);
  })

  // THIS FAILS. Expected: [Function bound checkType], actual: [Function bound checkType]
  it('validates propB', () => {
    expect(MyComponent.propTypes.propB)
      .toEqual(
        PropTypes.shape({
          inner1: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
          inner2: PropTypes.func,
        }).isRequired
      );
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Though I don't see the point of unit-testing this you could do the following:

Export your shape as different object

```
// some-descriptive-name-shape.js
export default {
   inner1: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
   inner2: PropTypes.func,
}
```

and make a unit test for it.

Or more general approach would be to use `sinon` to spy on `console.error` and do component render with invalid properties to see it calls your spy

```
let consoleError;

beforeEach(() => {
    consoleError = spyOn(console, 'error');
});

afterEach(() => {
    consoleError.restore();
})

it('should warn on empty propB, () => {
   // do shallow render of <MyComponent />
   expect(consoleError.called).toBe(true)
   // etc
})
```